# Running any NX command on Angular project gives ^[[12;1R error

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to run any command on my Monorepo using NX, but all of them have this error on the console and doesn't continue. Actually, it just stays there but doesn't complete or fails. I need to manually abort and stop, it was running for more than 20minutes and nothing happened.

Basically when I run any command like this:

```
nx run admin:serve:development
nx run admin:build:production
```

The console has this type of message:

[image]

Any idea what could be happening? It started to happen after I upgraded from Angular 16 to Angular 17 and NX from version 17 to 18. I did this using thow process from NX including the migrations to update all packages.

Also, after I start this command my computer becomes really really slow and VsCode takes up almost all ram usage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running `nx reset` and  `nx repair`. Hopefully, it's something from which NX can recover. And from my personal experience, it's a good thing to run `nx reset` once in a while

Comment: If you are using Angular 17.0.0, then you can use Nx 17.1.0, and if you are using Angular 17.2.0, then you can use Nx 18.1.1.

Comment: @mat.hudak I tried, it didn't worked either.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal But why does it work on my Mac with the same versions I have on my Windows?